# Should I let go of view-references etc in onStop() or onDestroy()?

Tags: android, memory, view, android-activity

Should I let go of views and other data i'm holding on to in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`?

- If I release my application's data in `onDestroy()` it won't be very memory-friendly towards android, am I correct? Since i'm still holding on to a couple of views after onStop(). Plus it's not guaranteed to be called and my Activity is purged from memory anyway.
- If I release it in `onStop()`, I have to add do my `setContentView()` etc. in `onStart()` which doesn't get the `Bundle` that `onCreate(Bundle)` is handed.

Note that I have a very large application which consists of dozens of Views, most of which are custom and added by code rather than layout-files. This is largely due to the fact that I had to create a custom pager to flip through pages, since none of the built-in Views could serve my purposes (I've tried… hard…).

I have read through all the relevant Android docs but I still have no real clue on what about the view-hierarchy Android saves/recreates by itself and what I have to do myself. Or when all of that happens, meaning when Android removes the view-hierarchy from memory.

**Update Question:**

The android docs says this: `Note: Because the system retains your Activity instance in system memory when it is stopped, it's possible that you don't need to implement the onStop() and onRestart() (or even onStart() methods at all.`

If it's ok to hold on to everything, why should I care about memory-leaks when my application is being stopped like [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/) article says? If it's destroyed and re-created, for example after a screen-rotation, I'm starting from scratch anyway?

Comment: even if you let go the references its still the job of gc to mark and sweep. The gc kicks in to free memory. suppose you have a bitmap. you can call bitmap.recycle() in onPause(). but its still the job of the gc to free memory

Comment: for getting the data ,  use the Activity method `getIntent()` to retrieve the current intent and likewise any extra's passed in it.

Comment: consider a situation where you have a background for each activity. You navigate from 1st activity to 2nd. 1st activity is paused. But not destroyed.Your first activity is in background. In such a cases you can load image in onResume() and unbind or recycle in onPause().  When gc  kicks in it free's memory. In such a situation it works Note: the os will destroy activities in background only when it needs to reclaim memory.

Comment: When orientation changes the activity is destroyed and recreated. Then you can do as what is mentioned above. Since onResume() will be called.

Comment: The article you linked to is discouraging re-using Views across Activities by keeping static references to the Views. This is bad because it prevents the Activity that created the view from being collected. A good general rule is to never keep a static reference to a View, Activity, or Context.

Comment: @Krylez i agree with you on this. this will lead to memory leaks. pls check the link for more information https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: I have a suggestion:  Just from the way this question is framed, it sounds to me as if you think that an Activity is an application.  It isn't.  If you think of your Activity as a servlet, then it doesn't hold any application data (a Service or a ContentProvider does that) and this entire question is moot.

Comment: I don't think that, but my application consists only of a single Activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, you do not have to let go of anything in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` **if** you only hold it in your activity (in its non-static fields). When Android let's go of your activity, the rest of your stuff is automatically thrown away (along with the activity), because there is no way to reach it from any thread (this is how Garbage Collectors work, it is not in any way special or specific to activities).
2. The article you refer to describes the problem where a reference to a view (or a drawable, or - broadly speaking - activity context) survives the activity that created it. Since there is a reference pointing back to the already dead activity, it becomes a zombie; what's more, it clings to all its fields, effectively zombifying them too. So if you have a view or a drawable and put it in a static field (or in any other place that might survive your activity object), then yes, you have to let it go in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` of the relevant activity.
3. If Android destroys your Activity and forgoes calling `onDestroy()`, it means that the whole process was taken down, and this means that no memory leak can occur anyway (they are local to a single process)

**Bonus answers:**

1. views inflated from XML files take exactly as much memory as ones built in code. Why should they be heavier?
2. (update, after a comment) before an activity gets thrown away, Android walks its whole view hierarchy and gives each view a chance to store its state (any parcelable data) into a bundle; when recreating view Android walks the tree again and gives the data back. This is why when you recreate an activity the state of the view is saved (focus, position, content of text fields etc.). Observe how the state is only saved for elements that have an id (does not matter if they are inflated or created dynamically).

Comment: I didn't mean they are heavier, just that i don't know how/if Android does some memory-magic with it's references to the view-hiearchy after onStop()/onPause().

Comment: Unfortunately as it seems I can't use onStop() or onDestroy(), because there's a 5-second lag before it's called. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748916/why-is-ondestroy-called-after-onresume-when-using-back-button

Comment: @fdreger - could you please tell me how to release views in onDestroy() ??

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille: No. It depends on how you hold them. Unless you made them stick around by doing something unwise, then it's ok not to release anything.